# Mapping columns from one dataframe to another to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

i have a dataframe

```
id  store    address
1    100        xyz
2    200        qwe
3    300        asd
4    400        zxc
5    500        bnm
```

i have another dataframe df2

```
serialNo    store_code  warehouse
    1          300         Land
    2          500         Sea
    3          100         Land
    4          200         Sea
    5          400         Land
```

I want my final dataframe to look like:

```
id  store    address  warehouse
1    100        xyz     Land
2    200        qwe     Sea
3    300        asd     Land
4    400        zxc     Land
5    500        bnm     Sea
```

i.e map from one dataframe onto another creating new column

Answer (score 67, accepted):

#### `df.merge`

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, left_on='store', right_on='store_code')
          .reindex(columns=['id', 'store', 'address', 'warehouse']))
print(out)

   id  store address warehouse
0   1    100     xyz      Land
1   2    200     qwe       Sea
2   3    300     asd      Land
3   4    400     zxc      Land
4   5    500     bnm       Sea
```

---

#### `pd.concat` + `df.sort_values`

```
u = df1.sort_values('store')
v = df2.sort_values('store_code')[['warehouse']].reset_index(drop=1)
out = pd.concat([u, v], 1)

print(out)

   id  store address warehouse
0   1    100     xyz      Land
1   2    200     qwe       Sea
2   3    300     asd      Land
3   4    400     zxc      Land
4   5    500     bnm       Sea
```

The first sort call is redundant assuming your dataframe is already sorted on `store`, in which case you may remove it.

---

#### `df.replace`/`df.map`

```
s = df1.store.replace(df2.set_index('store_code')['warehouse'])
print(s) 
0    Land
1     Sea
2    Land
3    Land
4     Sea

df1['warehouse'] = s
print(df1)

   id  store address warehouse
0   1    100     xyz      Land
1   2    200     qwe       Sea
2   3    300     asd      Land
3   4    400     zxc      Land
4   5    500     bnm       Sea
```

Alternatively, create a mapping explicitly. This works if you want to use it later.

```
mapping = dict(df2[['store_code', 'warehouse']].values)
df1['warehouse'] = df1.store.map(mapping)
print(df1)

   id  store address warehouse
0   1    100     xyz      Land
1   2    200     qwe       Sea
2   3    300     asd      Land
3   4    400     zxc      Land
4   5    500     bnm       Sea
```

Comment: how is map with large amounts of data, e.g. data frames 5 to 10 million? I wonder if that dict will work efficiently.

Comment: @DISC-O it depends on the data, but pandas generally does not work great at such scales of data. Think more along the lines of distributed processing eg dask.

Comment: which one is the fastest one ?

Comment: @Pablo It depends on your data, best is to test it with `%timeit` statements

Answer (score 30):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) or [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1['warehouse'] = df1['store'].map(df2.set_index('store_code')['warehouse'])
print (df1)
   id  store address warehouse
0   1    100     xyz      Land
1   2    200     qwe       Sea
2   3    300     asd      Land
3   4    400     zxc      Land
4   5    500     bnm       Sea
```

---

```
df1 = df1.join(df2.set_index('store_code'), on=['store']).drop('serialNo', 1)
print (df1)
   id  store address warehouse
0   1    100     xyz      Land
1   2    200     qwe       Sea
2   3    300     asd      Land
3   4    400     zxc      Land
4   5    500     bnm       Sea
```

Comment: i'm getting this error, when running .map code in a similar dataset.
 `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: I think there is problem you have duplicates in `store_code` in `df2`. so need `df1['store'].map(df2.drop_duplicates('store_code').set_index('store_code')['warehouse'])`

Comment: correct! Thanks :)