# How to find rows in a dataframe based on other rows and other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

From the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54455544/load-multi-nested-dict-json-into-pandas) I took a JSON response looking similar to this:

*(please note: `id`'s in my sample data below are numeric strings but some are alphanumeric)*

`data=↓**`

```
{
  "state": "active",
  "team_size": 20,
  "teams": {
    "id": "12345679",
    "name": "Good Guys",
    "level": 10,
    "attacks": 4,
    "destruction_percentage": 22.6,
    "members": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John",
        "level": 12
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Tom",
        "level": 11,
        "attacks": [
          {
            "attackerTag": "2",
            "defenderTag": "4",
            "damage": 64,
            "order": 7
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "opponent": {
    "id": "987654321",
    "name": "Bad Guys",
    "level": 17,
    "attacks": 5,
    "damage": 20.95,
    "members": [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Betty",
        "level": 17,
        "attacks": [
          {
            "attacker_id": "3",
            "defender_id": "1",
            "damage": 70,
            "order": 1
          },
          {
            "attacker_id": "3",
            "defender_id": "7",
            "damage": 100,
            "order": 11
          }
        ],
        "opponentAttacks": 0,
        "some_useless_data": "Want to ignore, this doesn't show in every record"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Fred",
        "level": 9,
        "attacks": [
          {
            "attacker_id": "4",
            "defender_id": "9",
            "damage": 70,
            "order": 4
          }
        ],
        "opponentAttacks": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I loaded this using:

```
df = json_normalize([data['team'], data['opponent']],
                     'members',
                     ['id', 'name'],
                     meta_prefix='team.',
                     errors='ignore')
print(df.iloc(1))
attacks              [{'damage': 70, 'order': 4, 'defender_id': '9'...
id                                                                   4
level                                                                9
name                                                              Fred
opponentAttacks                                                      0
some_useless_data                                                  NaN
team.name                                                     Bad Guys
team.id                                                      987654321
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

I have a 3 part question in essense.

1. How do I get a row like the one above using the member tag? I've tried:

   ```
   member = df[df['id']=="1"].iloc[0]
   #Now this works, but am I correctly doing this?
   #It just feels weird is all.
   ```
2. How would I retrieve a member's defenses based only given that only attacks are recorded and not defenses *(even though defender_id is given)*? I have tried:

   ```
   df.where(df['tag']==df['attacks'].str.get('defender_id'), df['attacks'], axis=0)
   #This is totally not working.. Where am I going wrong?
   ```
3. Since I am retrieving new data from an API, I need to check vs the old data in my database to see if there are any new attacks. I can then loop through the new attacks where I then display to the user the attack info.

   *This I honestly cannot figure out, I've tried looking into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863682/find-rows-in-a-dataframe-that-partially-match-conditions) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049658/mapping-columns-from-one-dataframe-to-another-to-create-a-new-column) as well that I felt were anywhere close to what I needed and am still having trouble wrapping my brain around the concept. Essentially my logic is as follows:*

   ```
   def get_new_attacks(old_data, new_data)
       '''params
            old_data: Dataframe loaded from JSON in database
            new_data: Dataframe loaded from JSON API response
                      hopefully having new attacks
          returns:
            iterator over the new attacks
       '''

       #calculate a dataframe with new attacks listed
       return df.iterrows()
   ```

I know the function above shows little to no effort other than the docs I gave *(basically to show my desired input/output)* but trust me I've been wracking my brain over this part the most. I've been looking into `merg`ing all attacks then doing `reset_index()` and that just raises an error due to the attacks being a list. The `map()` function in the second question I linked above has me stumped.

Comment: It's been an hour now, I apologize for the vague title, just edited. I don't know what happened there.

Comment: What's `df1`? is it `df.iloc[1]`?

Comment: That was supposed to be `df`. My bad, and I have been doing alot of research on how to use pandas. I found my answer, and @a_guest answered correctly.

Comment: Yeah, i was ready to say that too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your questions in order (code below):

1. I looks like `id` is a unique index of the data and so you can use `df.set_index('id')` which allows you to access data by player id via `df.loc['1']` for example.
2. As far as I understand your data, all the dictionaries listed in each of the `attacks` are self-contained in a sense that the corresponding player id is not needed (as `attacker_id` or `defender_id` seems to be enough to identify the data). So instead of dealing with a rows that contains lists I recommend swapping that data out in its own data frame which makes it easily accessible.
3. Once you store `attacks` in its own data frame you can simply compare indices in order to filter out the old data.

Here's some example code to illustrate the various points:

```
# Question 1.
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
print(df.loc['1'])  # For example player id 1.

# Question 2 & 3.
attacks = pd.concat(map(
    lambda x: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x).set_index('order'),  # Is 'order' the right index?
    df['attacks'].dropna()
))

# Question 2.
print(attacks[attacks['defender_id'] == '1'])  # For example defender_id 1.

# Question 3.
old_attacks = attacks.iloc[:2]  # For example.
new_attacks = attacks[~attacks.index.isin(old_attacks.index)]
print(new_attacks)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know these were novice questions. I was just getting started using pandas and was having trouble understanding it's nuances. Did alot of research these past day and have been watching videos. Thanks for the great answer!